# PayPal account credentials for developer

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to find out how to give a developer the least amount of access they need to my business `PayPal` account for my app.  How should I set this up so I protect my private account information from the developer while allowing them enough access to develop?

They need access to test and develop with the `PayPal APIs`.  I created a `sandbox` account for the app, I gave the developer the `Sandbox ID` and `API Credentials` along with the `sandbox` test accounts I created.

The developer asked if I could give them the login for my `PayPal developer` account so they can see the `Dashboard` for testing and see can `transactions`.  I don't think this is the right way or they could access my bank, and company information.

I have read the `PayPal` documentation for information about this but can't find much.  This [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/) has the most information I've found but not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In your account, go to your profile settings and find Manage Users. There you can add a user and select the amount of access they can have. Give them the username and password you make for them, NEVER give your email and password.

To get started using adding users to your account and managing their levels of access, log in to your PayPal account, go to your Profile, and click Manage Users under Account Information.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/permissions-outside

Comment: This was an option I considered at first but there was a problem with it.  I created a user and gave them the developer privileges recommended by PayPal which is under `Integration`, I checked
`API Activation & Authorization`.  This is the only privilege I gave the new user account but when I was testing it, I was able to request money from anyone.  I don't want to allow my developer to do this from my account.  It's strange, there is a check box for `Request Money and Send Invoices` which is not checked but the account can still do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your developer does not need access to your account at all, regular paypal.com or developer.paypal.com.

They would simply login to developer.paypal.com with their own PayPal account and create their own test accounts for use in the sandbox.  They can build your app using their own test accounts, and then hand it over to you so that you can simply update the API credentials with your live values and ensure the code is running live instead of against the sandbox at that point.

Comment: That's what I thought at first.  The developer is in India.  The developer told me that they aren't allowed to create a developer account using Classic API/Adaptive Payments, which is part of this application, if they are based in India.  It doesn't make sense to me why PayPal wouldn't allow that for development only.

Answer (score 2):

developer from India can  create Paypal sandbox account as i am also from India and created sandbox account.

Comment: The developer from India can create a sandbox but the developer is telling me that PayPal doesn't allow use of Classic API with Adaptive Payments from India even in sandbox for testing.  If you can show that you can please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, 
https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/mytools/apiaccess
go to paypal, all tools, you can see manage API, press update, then you'll see that screen. Im doing it right now, i don't know if it will work.